# React-Native , items in Drawer Navigator (React-Navigation) are not completely visible on some devices

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

**So the drawer in my app should Ideally look like this:**

[image]

**but instead it looks like this:**

[image]

I am creating it like this and passing it down to my stackNavigator

```
export const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator({
"Home":Home,
"Profile":Profile,
"Contact Us":Contact
},{ 
  contentComponent:DrawerComponent
})
```

My DrawerComponent is :

```
class Content extends React.Component<IProps>{

 render(){
  return (<View>
    <View
      style={{
        backgroundColor: '#f50057',
        height: 100,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
      }}
    >
      <Text style={{ color: 'white', fontSize: 15 }}>
        {this.props.name}
      </Text>
      <Text style={{ color: 'white', fontSize: 15 }}>
         {this.props.phone}
      </Text>
    </View>
    <DrawerItems {...this.props} />
  </View>
   )
 }
}
```

StackOverflow, any reading recommendations are welcome

Comment: whats the output if you just use it like: 'Contact Us: Contact' (without the quotation marks)

Comment: It has no effect, it's still the same, besides Home and Profile are also not getting rendered completely

Comment: can you update the question with your DrawerComponent code?

Comment: I have added it but I don't think it's relevant here, it's probably related to screen width

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dumber solution that I found to this question was to add space after my keys like this:

```
 export const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator({
 "Home ":Home,
 "Profile ":Profile,
 "Contact Us ":Contact,
 "Your Progress ":UserProgress
 },{ 
  contentComponent:DrawerComponent
 })
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the width you have given for the Textview?

There is something called a "Toggle Inspector" that will help you to debug the UI. Check this [link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging) to read its documentation.

Check if the width of the label/Text is proper.

Comment: If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted so that it will help others in future :-)

Comment: I wrapped my DrawerItems in a view tag with style='100%' and that did the trick.
thanks!